# How to live a plugin in jQuery?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

Is it possible to add a live function on a plugin?

The jPikcer plugin wont work I create it from a .live('click', function(e)

Example:
$('.Multiple').jPicker();

Thanks,
Gino

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for this, the closest equivalent for this is the [`.livequery()`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/) plugin.  [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is an **event** listener, listening for bubbling events, not new elements.

Alternatively, you run the plugin with that selector and a context when you're adding new elements, e.g. in a [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  //options...
  success: function(data) {
    $('.Multiple', data).jPicker();
  }
});
```